# Transforming the external link with in the site

Tags: feeds

sorry if the title is not apt, I'm new to Drupal. Here I'm working in drupal 7 the site has a news feed module, automatically updates the contents (links). When these links are clicked the corresponding links will be opened in the new tab or in the same tab (closing our actual site). So to avoid this, I would like display the corresponding link's page with in our drupal site. so that our drupal site will be active and the corresponding newsfeed link will be opened within our site (like wise displaying the web page in an iframe)

I tried of using iframes, but couldn't get what i wanted. I came across a module 'Fences' which looks good, but i couldn't know completely about the usage of fences module.

Can any one list out how to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using iframes is not a good option. Besides, I suggest to start using jQuery and update the function for the specific 'div'. We can add jQuery using JSinjector module, Navigate to JSinjector as Configuration/development/JSinjector.

Hope It would work fine in such a kind of issues.